# Git update cherry picked commit from PR

Tags: git, github

[image]

As seen in the figure, I have cherry picked Commit A from PR1 which is not merged into main.
Then I made some changes in Commit B and created a PR.
Now some more changes are amended into Commit A say Commit A.1.
But in my fork, the cherry picked commit is still Commit A.

Is it possible to Update Commit A to A.1 in my fork ?

Comment: Why Cherry pick, base you branch on your colleague work or merge it into yours

Comment: I believe if you just cherry-pick commit A1 from your colleague, you'll achieve the desired end-result (your history will still show both commits but I believe this is what you want). Do this on a test branch so you can easily drop it if it turns up it's not what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after many tests.

1. Cherry pick A.1 again into my fork (manually resolved merge conflicts)
2. Squash Commit A.1 and A